# How do i fix my canvas to show on page?

Tags: javascript, html

First time trying to build a html5 pong game. 
I cant seem to get canvas to show up with my code below. Along with that the paddles and ball aren't showing also. I cant seem to figure out where i went wrong below.
Any help would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Pong</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>

var WIDTH=700, HEIGHT=600, pi=Math.PI;
var UpArrow=38
var canvas, ctx, keystate;
var player, ai,ball;

player={
    x:null,
    y:null,
    width:20,
    height:100,

    update:function(){
        if (keystate[UpArrow]) this.y -=7;
        if (keystate[DownArrow]) this.y +=7;

        },
    draw: function(){
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);

        }
    };
ai={
    x:null,
    y:null,
    width:20,
    height:100,

    update:function(){},
    draw: function(){
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);

        }
        };
ball={
    x:null,
    y:null,
    vel:null,
    side:20,
    speed:5,

    update:function(){
        this.x += this.vel.x;
        this.y += this.vel.y;

        if(0>this.y || this.y+this.side> HEIGHT){
            this.vel.y ++-1;
        }

        },
    draw: function(){
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.side,this.side);

        }
        };




function main(){
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = WIDTH;
    canvas.width = HEIGHT;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    keystate = {};
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){
        keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });

    init();

    var loop = function(){
        update();
        draw();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    }

function init(){
    player.x = player.width;
    player.y = (HEIGHT - player.height)/2;

    ai.x = WIDTH - (player.width + ai.width);
    ai.y = (HEIGHT -ai.height)/2;

    ball.x = (WIDTH - ball.side)/2;
    ball.y = (HEIGHT - ball.side)/2;

    }

function update(){
    ball.update();
    player.update();
    ai.update();

    }

function draw(){
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

    ball.draw();
    player.draw();
    ai.draw();

    var w=4;
    var x = (WIDTH-w)*0.5;
    var y = 0;
    var step = HEIGHT/15;
    while(y < HEIGHT){
        ctx.fillRect(x, y+step*0.25, w, Step*0.5);
        y +=step;   
    }

    ctx.restore();

    }

main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `this.vel.y ++-1;` what?
- `keystate[evt.keyCode];` should be `keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;`
- you're trying to access undefined properties: `this.x += this.vel.x;` where have you defined `vel.x` before?
- `player` method, `keystate[UpArrow]`... where have you defined your `UpArrow` variables?
- take a look at your `main()` function you have: `document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){` and than you're setting `keystate[evt.keyCode];` Do you know that's returned from `evt.keyCode`? Clearly not `UpArrow` and `DownArrow`
- In your `draw()` function you use both `Step` and `step` variables. One is clearly `undefined`. Decide which one you want to use.
- `window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);` ? what's canvas doing here?

if you followed the above this is what you should finally get:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hulupo/1/edit?html,js,output)***

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to see all my errors from following a online example. First time coding javascript and html5.